# Enable to process a json response in retrofit2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

1) Json response.

```
  {
"customer_info": {
    "customer_id": "1",
    "customer_group_id": "1",
    "store_id": "0",
    "firstname": "john",
    "lastname": "kam",
    "email": "johnoconner@gmail.com",
    "telephone": "+3458690730867",
    "fax": "",
    "password": "c5bf3e452f02e3c639ce8513245d500cfdfbad9c",
    "salt": "qXXoVmh0j",
    "cart": null,
    "wishlist": null,
    "newsletter": "0",
    "address_id": "1",
    "custom_field": "",
    "ip": "45.113.251.60",
    "status": "1",
    "approved": "1",
    "verified": "0",
    "safe": "0",
    "token": "",
    "date_added": "2017-03-08 15:49:28"
},
"error_warning": "",
"redirect": "",
"success": "",
"email": "johnoconner@gmail.com",
"password": "12345678"
}
```

2)Using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for making a java class.

3)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://.in/?route=api/web_api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        LoginInterface loginInterface=retrofit.create(LoginInterface.class)

  Call<Example> call = loginInterface.checkUserExistOrNot("abc@gmail.com", "12345");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                Log.i("response is",response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

4)The error i get is

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

5) Scratch to many thing but didn't understant what was the wrong.

6) i'm attaching my java class also.

Comment: What do you see with this lo `Log.i("response is",response.body().toString());`

Comment: it's not excecute.

Comment: you don't see the log at all then you must see a stacktrace with exceptions with `t.printStackTrace();`

Comment: it's giving a com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Comment: your response is a string which should be a json object. You need to check your response

Comment: what i have to do to get json object.

Comment: you need to check what your getting on the client side and also check whether your server is responding with string or json object

Comment: Respose i posted above will work fine from browser.but on time of retrofit it's error.

Comment: give me a minute let me check your code

Comment: or atleast post the link that you use to open response on borwser

Comment: http://thefruitbowl.in/?route=api/web_api/login&email=nvranpariya@gmail.com&password=12345678

Comment: i am getting response. i made few changes will post answer

Comment: Issue in category.and pojo is
1)https://www.dropbox.com/s/blumxq74ginldgz/CatogoryResponse.java?dl=0
2)https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsrsjnmcbw7bg3d/Category.java?dl=0

Comment: pls check the edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base url must be **http://thefruitbowl.in/** and your endpoint ?**route=api/web_api/login**.

The retrofit call

```
public void retrofitTest()
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://thefruitbowl.in/") // not the base url
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    LoginInterface loginInterface=retrofit.create(LoginInterface.class);
    Call<Example> exampleCall = loginInterface.checkUserExistOrNot("abc@gmail.com", "12345");
    exampleCall.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, retrofit2.Response<Example> response) {
            Example example = response.body();
            Log.i("response",example.getEmail());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

And the interface

```
public interface LoginInterface
{

    @GET("?route=api/web_api/login")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    Call<Example> checkUserExistOrNot(@Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String password);
}
```

And i do get the response

```
 response: abc@gmail.com
```

For the commented url the pojos

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CategoryResponse {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private int success;
@SerializedName("categories")
@Expose
private List<Category> categories = null;

public int getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(int success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public List<Category> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}
```

}

then

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Category {

@SerializedName("category_id")
@Expose
private String categoryId;
@SerializedName("parent_id")
@Expose
private String parentId;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private Boolean image;
@SerializedName("href")
@Expose
private String href;
@SerializedName("categories")
@Expose
private Object categories;

public String getCategoryId() {
return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getParentId() {
return parentId;
}

public void setParentId(String parentId) {
this.parentId = parentId;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Boolean getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(Boolean image) {
this.image = image;
}

public String getHref() {
return href;
}

public void setHref(String href) {
this.href = href;
}

public Object getCategories() {
return categories;
}

public void setCategories(Object categories) {
this.categories = categories;
}

}
```

Your interface

```
public interface LoginInterface
    {

        @GET("?route=api/web_api/login")
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        Call<Example> checkUserExistOrNot(@Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String password);

        @GET("?route=api/web_api/categories")
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        Call<CategoryResponse> get()

    }
```

Your call

```
public void retrofitTest2()
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://thefruitbowl.in/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    LoginInterface loginInterface=retrofit.create(LoginInterface.class);
    Call<CategoryResponse> categoryResponseCall = loginInterface.get();

    categoryResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<CategoryResponse> response) {
            CategoryResponse categoryResponse = response.body();
            if(categoryResponse!=null)
            {
                Log.i("response",categoryResponse.getCategories().get(0).getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Make one more call base URL will be same

Comment: Except the second call has no query params

Comment: yup but it's giving again same error with this category.i thing problem in interface.

Comment: Only end point changes. You need one more method in interface with end point ?route=api/web_api/categories

Comment: ya i added that method but it's again giving me java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 may be i missing something.

Comment: You need a different pojo

Comment: i added pojo. categoryresponse.

Comment: Give me 2 mins will reply

Comment: post your pojos

Comment: there is chat on stackvoerflow you can invite others user to chat. Of course you need certain privileges.

Answer (score 0):

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Please make sure that the output response received from the server is fine. Check for double quotes.

Comment: what do you mean by ""